# Plesk scheduled backups stopped working - how to fix?

Tags: cron, centos, backup, plesk

My Plesk scheduled weekly backups suddenly stoped working. They just don't execute since a few weeks ago. When I manually trigger backups, all is ok. What could go wrong, what should I check first?

I'm running Plesk 9.5.4 on Linux Cent OS 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You updated mysql to 5.5. It breaks backupmng. The following query in the psa database will probably fix it:

`ALTER TABLE BackupsScheduled MODIFY COLUMN backup_day INTEGER;`

Comment: Thanks. Afraid to try your advice. Will this break my tables?